# Building Rust project alongside .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, rust, msbuild, pinvoke

Is there any way to build a Rust project with a C# .NET Core project when invoking `dotnet build`? The project structure is as follows:

```
<Root>
  > Engine
    Main.cs
  > Native
    > src
      lib.rs
    Cargo.toml
  Root.sln
```

I am using P/Invoke to call the rust `Native` library from `Engine`, and I want a convenience step to build both the rust project and the c# project when `dotnet build` is invoked, including setup such as copying of the rust `Native` library into the output folder of the c# project etc.

*Extra*: If possible, is there any way to 'bundle' the `Native` library into the compiled c# `Engine`?

Comment: You can try to write [Custom Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2019) and add it to your .NET Core project. Have never tried it with .NET Core actually but as far as I understand it should work.

Comment: You should also be able to define a [custom script](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#scripts). Simply invoke cargo there and copy and whatever however you like. I am quite sure there is no way to bundle it with the engine though, and that probably wouldn't be a good idea either.